# Emitter node not fading in

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm trying to fade in an emitter node which needs to start as if around 100 seconds were already passed from the start of the animation, so in my code i have this line when i set up the emitter:

```
 emitter.advanceSimulationTime(100);
```

Then later, when i need to add it to my scene I do this:

```
 worldNode.add(emitter);
 emitter.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration:2.0));
```

But the emitter suddenly pops up as if the fadeIn wasn't even there. If i remove the advanceSimulationTime call the emitter fades in as expected but unfortunately i need it. I tried a few different things but nothing worked, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the emitter on another SKNode, and fade that node's opacity, via its [`alpha`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483023-alpha) property. This will give you a visual fade in of the active emitter in the manner you desire, since the alpha property is propagated down the hierarchy.

From the Apple docs...

> **Declaration**
>
> `var alpha: CGFloat { get set }`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> *The default value is 1.0*
>
> The SKNode class does not perform drawing, but many of its subclasses
> do. When a node or any of its descendants are drawn, the alpha
> component of each pixel is multiplied by the node’s alpha property and
> then clamped to the range 0.0-1.0. This modified alpha value is used
> to blend the pixel into the framebuffer. Subclasses that render
> content define properties that determine the blending operations used
> in conjunction with the alpha value to blend pixels into the parent’s
> framebuffer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that asap.